# JsonLayout in webservice target without root parameter in NLog

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I would like to have JsonLayout in web service target so that I can use `includeAllProperties="true"`

```
<target xsi:type="WebService"
            name="ws"
            url="http://localhost:59802/api/hello/indexer"
            protocol="JsonPost"
            encoding="UTF-8">
<parameter name="root">
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
     <attribute name="Level" layout="${level}" />
     <attribute name="Timestamp" layout="${longdate}" />
     <attribute name="Message" layout="${message}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
</target>
```

This creates the following output

```
{ "root" : { "level" : "info", "message" : "xxx", "event1" : "aaa" } }
```

Actually, I would like to have as following

```
{ "level" : "info", "message" : "xxx", "event1" : "aaa" }
```

Does Nlog support to directly use JsonLayout instead of wrapping in `<parameter />`? Or there any ways to hack around and achieve this output? `file and console` support it but web service target does not seem too. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not alone: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1905

Comment: @RolfKristensen Is this feature not yet merged to master?

Comment: No it is an adventure up for graps, ready for anyone with guts and courage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog 4.5 allows you use a parameter without name. Like this:

```
<target xsi:type="WebService"
            name="ws"
            url="http://localhost:59802/api/hello/indexer"
            protocol="JsonPost"
            encoding="UTF-8">
<parameter name="">
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true">
     <attribute name="Level" layout="${level}" />
     <attribute name="Timestamp" layout="${longdate}" />
     <attribute name="Message" layout="${message}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
</target>
```